# Summing each element of two arrays

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, logic

I have two arrays and want to sum each element of both arrays and find the maximum sum.
I have programmed it like this:

```
sum = []
for element in arrayOne:
    sum.append(max([item + element for item in arrayTwo]))
print max(sum)
```

is there any better way to achieve this?

Comment: Can you give some examples? It's not very clear to me.

Answer (score 3):

You can use numpy.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array(arrayOne)
b = np.array(arrayTwo)
max = max(a + b)
print(max)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) with `max`:

```
from itertools import product
print(max(sum(x) for x in product(arrayOne, arrayTwo)))
```

Or using map:

```
print(max(map(sum,product(arrayOne, arrayTwo))))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
max_sum = max(map(sum, zip(arrayOne, arrayTwo)))
```

**Upd.**
If you need max from sum of all elements in array:

```
max_sum = max(sum(arrayOne), sum(arrayTwo))
```

If `arrayOne` and `arrayTwo` are nested lists (`[[1, 2], [3, 3], [3, 5], [4, 9]]`) and you need to find element with max sum:

```
max_sum = max(map(sum, arrayOne + arrayTwo))
```

***P. S.*** *Next time, please, provide examples of input and output to not let us guess what do you need.*

Comment: This pairs the values, not each element on the lists.

Answer (score 1):

To find a maximum of all pairwise sums of elements of two arrays of lengths *n* and *m* respectively one can just

```
max(arrayOne) + max(arrayTwo)
```

which would perform at worst in ***O(max(n, m))*** instead of ***O(n*m)*** when going over all the combinations.

**However**, if, for whatever reason, it is necessary to iterate over all the pairs, the solution might be

```
max(foo(one, two) for one in arrayOne for two in arrayTwo)
```

Where `foo` can be any function of two numeric parameters outputting a number (or an object of any class that implements [ordering](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons)).

<sub>By the way, please avoid redefining [built-ins](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) like `sum` in your code.</sub>